# How to observe that system alert disappeared

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, uilocalnotification

I'd like to in my app ask user to allow local notifications (I have switch for that purpose). When user interact with switch, I call standard registerUserNot.. But if user don't allow that, I'd like to return switch to off position. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the response in the app delegate call back:

```
application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:
```

and react accordingly.